At narrow widths, how to scale body element and children so that it fits client width and height?
I'm near the end of implementing a new website. It adjusts "responsively" to width changes at widths larger than typical mobile device widths, but I wish to scale the existing design to fit any narrower widths proportionately, if this is possible using fairly simple CSS. My media queries work fine for my major size breakpoints.
I tried using body {scale(.8)} and body {transform: scale(.8)}, but such solutions only scale by a fixed amount, rather than scaling to fit the screen (client) width exactly.
I also tried body {transform:scale(calc(100vw / 1920px))}, but this doesn't work either.
I don't want to just scale the font, or other such shortcuts. I want true fixed-aspect ratio scaling to fit the maximum of the width and height of the device, with any excess width or height filled with a white rectangle, or ignored.
I tried discussing it with Code-Llama-34b, but it kept going around in circles and confusing my question with "how to center an element".
I don't want to use any special libraries, or complex JavaScript calculations.
A simple "it can't be done" is acceptable if it is really true.

first of all, what is the size of body to start with? then you can find where it needs to be rescaled , probably via mediaqueries as a first step. There is also container queries, but from body, mediaquerie should be fine enough

Are you using a viewport meta tag? Have you tried adjusting the width value? Or leaving the tag out altogether?

Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Frankly, scaling a layout to match the current device widths is not really how responsive - design should work.  But maybe you have good reasons for it so please add an example - ideally as a running snippet to illustrate your use case.

I definitely cannot use the viewport meta tag, because that would scale at all widths and so would look horrible.
